# Use an image of an ImageField for an other ImageField. Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-facebook

I'm using django_facebook. Each time a user registers with fb, her profilpicture is loaded on a field called 'image'

In my models.py I have a field, named profilpic, to allow users to have a profil picture:

```
        class UserProfile(FacebookProfileModel):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User)
            profilpic = models.ImageField(upload_to="profilepics/", default="profilepics/shadow_user.jpg")


        def create_facebook_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
             if not created:
                return
             UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

        post_save.connect(create_facebook_profile, sender=User)
```

What I would like to do is when a user registers with facebook, the 'profilpic' takes the value of 'image' (i.e profilpic becomes the facebook picture).

Here is what I tried:

```
        def create_facebook_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
             if not created:
                return
             UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
             instance.userprofile.profilpic = instance.userprofile.image
             instance.save()

        post_save.connect(create_facebook_profile, sender=User)
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea on how to accomplish that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `instance` is a `User` object, not a `UserProfile` object so you need to call `instance.userprofile.save()` instead of `instance.save()`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the save method on the wrong instance. If you say instance.save() its only going to call its save method not the userprofile save method.

```
def create_facebook_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
             if not created:
                return
             UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
             instance.userprofile.profilpic = instance.userprofile.image
             instance.userprofile.save()
```